# Regular expression for any letter or number followed by a parenthesis

Tags: regex

Apparently I need some help with regular expressions. I am trying to find any letter or number followed by a parenthesis. `l)` `9)` `R)`.

I tried a couple of things. My idea was "starts with any letter or number followed by 1 parenthesis." So I tried this:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]\({1}
```

Obviously it did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're matching against an opening parenthesis whereas the example strings contain a closing one. You can match either of them using the below regex (there's no need for the `{1}` quantifier):

```
[A-Za-z0-9][()]
```

`[()]` matches either `(` or `)` -- there's no need to escape them when they are in square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, for what you're asking, your after:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][\(\)]
```

Your example's looking for just open parenthesis, and just at the very start of a line, so that would be:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]\(
```

So you're correct. Maybe you're having issues with the quoting of '('s, but that would depend on how you're using/supplying the regex, and to what. Or, maybe you've got other characters before the number, eg. spaces and/or tabs, which would not be matched?